# Is it possible to receive and count time in Modelsim?

Tags: vhdl, fpga, hdl, modelsim, test-bench

Is it possible to receive and count time in Modelsim?

For instance, I want to reset a sensor. The sensors reset require a logic '1' within 60 µs, so my code sends it. I need to catch the signal in a testbench file. May I write something like that?

```
if signal = '1' for 60 us then...
```

It would be like a command wait: `wait for 100 us;`, but vice versa.

I've tried to do it by creating a additional clock signal and count the rising edges. However, I hope there is a simpler decision.

upd.
so, in my case I don't no a right code, however I will try to explain in detail.

```
entity testbench is
end entity testbench;

architecture tb of testbench is

    signal reset_signal : std_logic;
    signal flag_success : std_logic;

begin

    RESET_PROCESS : process -- example process
    begin
        reset_signal <= '1';
        wait for 100 us;
        reset_signal <= '0';
        report "End simulation" severity failure;
    end process RESET_PROCESS;

    SENSOR_PROCESS : process
    begin
        -- i don't now how to write it correctly
        -- pseudocode
        if reset_signal = '1' within 60 us then
            flag_success <= '1';
        else
            flag_success <= '0';
        end if;
    end process;

end architecture tb;
```

The RESET_PROCESS like my programm, It sends reset_signal for 60 us. The SENSOR_PROCESS should recieve the reset_signal.
I can add a clk in the SENSOR_PROCESS, and can count the rising_edges. However, It is modelsim, It knows all timing characteristics, so I think it is possible to do it without the clk.

I've found attributes and written a code:

```
    if reset_signal = '0' then
        if reset_signal'quiet(60 us) then
            flag_success <= '1';
        else
            flag_success <= '0';
        end if;
    end if;

    -- or

    if reset_signal = '0' then
        wait for 60 us;
        if reset_signal'stable(60 us) then
            flag_success <= '1';
        else
            flag_success <= '0';
        end if;
    end if;
```

Unfortunately, the code doesn't work..

Comment: Maybe I 've foung the answer.
There is an predefined attribute S'STABLE(t)  is true if no even has occurred on signal S for t units of time.
So, I will try.

Comment: If you are wanting to make hardware, to synthesise, then you will have to cerate an additional clock signal and count the rising edges. `S'stable` is not synthesisable.

Comment: @MatthewTaylor The OP wants this for a testbench, presumably there is no need for synthesis.

Comment: You might like to provide a [example].

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check that after 60us data still will be '1' then you can do it by:

```
...
wait for 60 us;
if (reset == '1') then
    wait for 1 ns;
    if (reset == '0') then
        flag_success <= '1';
    else
        flag_success <= '1';
   end if
else
    flag_success <= '0';
end if;
```

If you want to check data through all the 60us maybe you can do something like:

```
...
for i in loop 0 to 60
if (reset == '1') then
...
else
wait for 1 us;
end if;
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that suits my requirements:

```
SENSOR_PROCESS : process
begin
    if reset_signal'stable(60 us) and (reset_signal = '0') then
        flag_success <= '1';
    else
        flag_success <= '0';
    end if;
    wait for 1 us;
end process;
```

The last WAIT statement like clock signal, however if somethind happends between cycle of the process, code will recognaize it.

Thanks)